# For each option in a matchmaker, make sure that at least one (but no more than one) matches per option

Tags: mysql, select

This will take a little explaining (moreso because I can't use the word "question" in the title of a question):

I have a matchmaker quiz with the following tables (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE `Quiz` (
  `quiz_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`quiz_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Quiz_1` (`code`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Quiz_Question` (
  `quiz_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `question_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `question` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, -- Lookup table of type of question: booean, radio, select, multiselect
  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Quiz_Answer` (
  `question_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `answer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `answer` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`answer_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Quiz_Response` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `quiz_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `question_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `answer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `Response_1` (`user_id`,`question_id`,`answer_id`),
  KEY `Response_2` (`question_id`,`answer_id`)
);
```

All pretty straightforward so far.

Previously, the query went like this (simplified):

```
SELECT u.login, COUNT( u.user_id ) AS matches, ...
FROM User u
INNER JOIN Quiz_Response rep ON u.user_id = rep.user_id
WHERE u.active = 1
AND ( 
    (rep.question_id = 3 AND rep.answer_id IN (20, 24)) OR 
    (rep.question_id = 10 AND rep.answer_id IN (83,84,85))
)
GROUP BY u.user_id
HAVING matches >= 2
ORDER BY u.login
```

**Note:** *I've removed things like whether something is active or not, display order, blocked users, date ranges, etc from the CREATE TABLE and query to focus on the core problem.*

So if a user answered question3 with either 20 or 24, they show up in the results once, and if they answer question10 with either 83, 84, or 85 they show up a second time. The query then counts the number of times any given user shows up and if it is equal or greater than the number of questions tried to match, it is considered a match (in this case the matchmaker checked two possible questions so their should be at least 2 entries (matches).

My issue is that I'm introducing a multiple choice matches. This has the end result of a single question can have multiple matches which throws off the counting.

So, if a searcher says that they are looking for people that answered question 5 with either A, B, or C, and a user says that they like A, B, and C, that becomes three matches essentially nullifying two other questions (searched for three things, and got back three matches just all from the same question).

So the question I'm asking is how do I check that for every given question, it only scores 1 match, even if multiple answers for a single question match multiple times.

Hope that all makes sense.

Comment: TL; DR; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry, better?

Comment: Come on. It's 3 steps. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of counting on `u.user_id`, count on `distinct rep.question_id`:

```
SELECT u.login, u.user_id, COUNT(distinct rep.question_id) AS matches
FROM User u
INNER JOIN Quiz_Response rep ON u.user_id = rep.user_id
WHERE u.active = 1
AND ( 
    (rep.question_id = 3 AND rep.answer_id IN (20, 24)) OR 
    (rep.question_id = 10 AND rep.answer_id IN (83,84,85))
)
GROUP BY u.user_id
HAVING matches >= 2
ORDER BY u.login;
```

So if my `Quiz_Response` table looks like this:

```
+-------------+---------+-------------+-----------+---------+
| response_id | quiz_id | question_id | answer_id | user_id |
+-------------+---------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|           1 |       1 |           1 |         4 |       3 |
|           2 |       2 |           3 |        20 |       2 |
|           3 |       2 |           3 |        24 |       2 |
|           4 |       4 |          10 |        83 |       1 |
|           5 |       4 |          10 |        84 |       1 |
|           6 |       4 |          10 |        85 |       1 |
|           7 |       2 |           3 |        20 |       4 |
|           8 |       1 |           1 |         1 |       4 |
|           9 |       2 |           3 |        24 |       4 |
|          10 |       4 |          10 |        83 |       4 |
+-------------+---------+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

Output of the above query will be:

```
+---------------------+---------+---------+
| login               | user_id | matches |
+---------------------+---------+---------+
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 |       4 |       2 |
+---------------------+---------+---------+
```